# callback function after get data from server

Tags: angular, callback

I want to get a value after web page Oninit, and there is my code.

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getVideo(this.getScore);
}

 getVideo(callback) {
    this.dataService.getVideo(this.videoID).subscribe(
        data => this.video = data,
        error => console.log(error)
    );
    if (typeof callback === 'function')
        callback();
}

getScore() {
    console.log(this.video['Score']);
}
```

I can render my video score on page if there are not any errors, but in the callback make it error.

```
caused by: Cannot read property 'video' of undefined
```

How can I get values after get data from server? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> caused by: Cannot read property 'video' of undefined

This is happening because of the dataService is executed in async and before your service returns data back your callback() function is already executed.

Try calling your callback() inside the data function of subscribe.

```
getVideo(callback) {
    this.dataService.getVideo(this.videoID).subscribe(
        data => { 
           this.video = data;
           if (typeof callback === 'function')
              callback();
        },
        error => console.log(error)
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of `"this"` context, try this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   this.getVideo(this.getScore.bind(this));
}
```